$\operatorname{Hom}_k(R,k)$ is injective indecomposable $R$-module for $R$ local $k$-algebra of finite $k$-dimension
I am working on Exercise 3.1.22. from Bruns and Herzog's Cohen-Macaulay rings. The exercise in question is the following (the references I will use are of course from within the book):

It appears before the theory of Matlis duality is explained. Proving that it is injective as $R$-module is just using 3.1.6.
For the indecomposability, once you have Matlis duality, you just have to realise that $\operatorname{Hom}_k(R,k)$ is $E_R(k)$ (see this pdf, with solutions to some of the exercises of this fantastic book) (edit: this is a mistake, because $k$ doesn't have to be the residue field as Mohan points out in the comments.)
However, I think I proved that it is indecomposable by an argument that does not involve but elemental arguments. Is it correct?
Suppose that $\operatorname{Hom}_k(R,k) = M_1\oplus M_2$ where the $M_i$ are $R$-modules. Now,
$$
R\cong \operatorname{Hom}_k(\operatorname{Hom}_k(R,k),k) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_k(M_1\oplus M_2,k) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_k(M_1,k)\oplus \operatorname{Hom}_k(M_2,k)
$$
where the isomorphisms are a priori $k$-linear isomorphism due to $R$ being a finite $k$-vector space, but one can check that they are also $R$-module isomorphisms.
Thus, we decomposed $R = P_1\oplus P_2$, a local ring, as a direct sum of two $R$-submodules, which implies that one of them is zero, say $P_1=0$. Thus, $\operatorname{Hom}_k(M_1,k)=0$, which for $k$-vector spaces is the case only when $M_1=0$. We conclude that $\operatorname{Hom}_k(R,k)$ is indecomposable.
What do you think?

$E_R(k)$ does not make sense, since $k$ is not an $R$- module in general. I think you mean the injective hull of the residue field.

@Mohan thanks for pointing that out! I realised that also in the PDF it is mistakingly assumed that $k$ is the residue field of the ring, which is not the case in general. I wonder whether the proof could be fixed. After all, the exercise does imply that $\hom_k(R,k)$ is the injective hull of the residue field!
